# Augmented reality in worklight

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, augmented-reality

I'm trying to implement some augmented reality function to my application.
I found the Wikitude SDK with is PhoneGap plugin, but i wonder if there are othere similar plugin more suitable with worklight, because i sa this link:
https://www-01.ibm.com/software/success/cssdb.nsf/CS/CPAR-8TNQF4

It is about Lotte Card, an application based on worklight that uses some augmented reality function.
Do you know wich framework did they use?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information about which Cordova plug-in Lotte Card is using is unknown.

Also, I think the question you should ask is whether the Cordova plug-in you've found is of quality and not if it works with Worklight. When you use a Cordova plug-in it is "on its own". Worklight is not doing any magic to make it work, it is Cordova that does all the lifting...

So your best approach IMO is to try and implement it. Even w/out Worklight in the picture. You can then simply follow the IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules about how to use Cordova plug-ins in a Worklight-based application.

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova

Comment: No, no Idan, I understood this, maybe I badly explained myself.
I have already tried Wikitude and made it working with Worklight, but I'm just asking if there is something more "common" for worklight.
I know that phonegap and worklight could be seen as the same thing when talking about plugins (just to simplify) so i was wondering if there is something better after i saw LotteCard.

Comment: There is nothing common about augmented reality.